# Getting the list of sponsors

Tags: youtube-data-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I'm working with a Youtuber with over 1mil subscribers and we need to fetch the list of sponsors when users log-in to check if they're sponsoring the channel, if they do they get access to a specific part of the website.
I went through the API docs and couldn't find a way to do it,
am I missing something?

thank you for your help in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Youtube Data API has [Members](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/members) resource that returns the list of members (sponsors) of a channel. It also returns membership level of each member.

```sh
curl \
  'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/members?part=snippet&mode=all_current&maxResults=1000&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --compressed
```

**EDIT:** Updated answer to Members resource instead of Sponsor resource (deprecated as of 2020-03-31)